# VIM set ctags in .vimrc

Tags: vim, ctags

I have my projects in /srv/http/dev folder. I generated ctags file for one project:

```
$ ctags -R --languages=php .
```

Now I set ctags path:

```
:set tags=/srv/http/dev/proj/tags
```

And it's working fine.

But I have many projects in dev/ folder. How can I set ctags in .vimrc file? `set tags=tags` not working properly.

And I would like to generate tags file by pressing hotkey on selected NERDTree folder. I tried:

```
nmap <silent> <F4>
    \ :!ctags -R
    \ --languages=php .<CR>
```

But it creates tags file in home folder and shows warnings about scanning home folder..

**EDIT:**
As @Alexandru Plugaru advised I should use g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected() function.

I am just newbie vim user, so I have one more question. I have added in my .vimrc file:

```
function createTags()
    let curNodePath = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected().path.str
    exec ':!ctags -R --languages=php ' . curNodePath
endfunction
nmap <silent> <F4> :execute createTags()<CR>
```

But by pressing on F4 I see:

```
E117: Unknown function: createTags
E15: Invalid expression: createTags
```

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to @Alexandru Plugaru I got this:

```
function CreateTags()
    let curNodePath = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected().path.str()
    exec ':!ctags -R --languages=php -f ' . curNodePath . '/tags ' . curNodePath
endfunction
nmap <silent> <F4> :call CreateTags()<CR>
```

And it works! By pressing F4 I get tags file in project folder.

Comment: try :call createTags() also try naming the function with a capital letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the current directory of vim is the home directory. You either need to change the path or create nerdtree plugin. See nerdtree_plugin directory for an example. I think that you'll find this function interesting:

`g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected()`

Comment: Thanks, I think it is what I need. Can you answer on more question please? See my EDIT.

Comment: I responded on the original post

Answer (score 49):

1. Functions are supposed to start with a capital letter. Change `createTags` to `CreateTags`.
2. To use project-specific `tags` files you will need to add something like that to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   set tags=./tags,tags;
   ```

   so that Vim looks for a `tags` file in the current directory first and up and up until it finds it. Additionnaly, I like to `set autochdir`: the working directory is always the one containing the current file.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I can't understand how to do it) I added `set tags=./tags,tags` and `set autochdir` in my .vimrc file. But tags not founded because vim starts to find them from /home..

Comment: Vim starts from home because it's probably the working directory. What does `:pwd` says?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry) I forgot semicolon after `set tags=./tags,tags`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the semicolon behavior documented anywhere? It's not mentioned in `:help 'tags'`.

Comment: Found it: `help file-searching`

Answer (score -1):

in your .vimrc use:

```
 set tags+=tags,/srv/http/dev/proj/tags
```

I believe that comma is the proper separator.

Comment: Ok, it's works. But what about more one projects. After creating new project I must add full path to this new project? And so again and again? May be it can be automated?

Comment: using `./tags;` as mentioned in another answer is highly preferable to hard-coding paths in .vimrc.

Comment: you could also use https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc to have a "local vimrc" per project where you define different tags.